# mysql sum(column2 - column1) with rollup

Tags: mysql, sum, formula, rollup

i need some help with my mysql query . I have one table that look like :

[image]

And then i want to select with this query :

```
select id, class, defaut, input, round(input - defaut) test from table1
group by class, id with rollup
```

I want the output like :

[image]

But my query given me like that :

[image]

please for your help, thanks

Comment: I think you could illustrate the problem with fewer rows and/or an sqlfiddle/rextest.

Comment: You SELECT id, class, defaut, and input, but only group by two of those columns. While there is a functional dependancy in place, for the purposes of ROLLUP, this doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sum the default, input and the calculated fields to get the expected output, otherwise `rollup` will simply return the value from the last record:

```
select id, class, sum(defaut), sum(input), sum(round(input - defaut)) test from table1
group by class, id with rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Query :

```
select id, class, sum(defaut), sum(input), sum(input - defaut) test from
 table1 
group by class, id with rollup
```

[image]

Thank for your helps.